# React functional component rerenders when props don't change (using useSelector)

Tags: react-hooks, react-redux, react-component

I'm trying to understand why a change in my `component B` triggers a re-render of `component A` and his children.

`component A` has a `useSelector` for `store.A`.
`component B` has a `useSelector` for `store.B`.
`store A` and `store B` are under the same `AppStore`.

`component A` has several children components that are not connected to the store (`component A` retrieves all the data needed from the store and passes it as `props`).

When `component B` calls an action that modifies `store B`, `useSelector` is called in both components.

*Here comes the catch:*
If I write a `useEffect` that watches all the data retrieved via `useSelector` in `component A`, it never triggers when interacting with `component B`.

**But it re-renders all the child components all the same.**

I've tried to `React.memo` a child component of `component A`, and no change, it always re-renders `component A` and all his children, even when its props doesn't change (or so is telling me the `useEffect` watching all the component `props`).

Note 1: all components are functional.
Note 2: if `component B` only changes its local state and doesn't call any redux actions, `component A` is never re-rendered.

I also double checked that all the functions passed as props are using `useCallback`.

I really don't understand what is going on.
I thought that if a component props don't change, they shouldn't re-render.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked in the comment of the question, here is my answer:

It was the main App component that was using a function with the result of a useState, forcing the re-render of both components whenever the state changed.

Even with my other error fixed, if you are doing:

```
type ReduxProps = {
  propertyA: string | null;
  propertyA: string | null;
};

const { propertyA, propertyB } = useSelector<AppState, ReduxProps>(state => ({
  propertyA: state.A.property,
  propertyB: state.B.property
}));
```

it will trigger a re-render, because it wraps the properties in a new object every time.

Prefer doing:

```
  const propertyA = useSelector<AppState, string | null>(state => state.A.property);
  const propertyB = useSelector<AppState, string | null>(state => state.B.property);
```

(if I'm wrong please correct me because this was what we discovered).

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide piece of your code (preferably the impacted component and slice) so we can have a better understanding? You mentioned useEffect, what do you have in your dependency array? Are there any extra reducers that you would be calling with your useSelector?

For starters I would try using an empty dependency array with your useEffect and debug from there.

```
useEffect(() => { // Your code here }, [//leave this empty for now and check console after refresh])
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. It was the father of both components that had a variable calling a function, and caused the re-render of both whenever the state changed. Just took me 3h to find it :')

Comment: Glad you got it going, happy coding!